# How to "slurp" multiple files with Ansible

Tags: ansible, yaml

With Ansible, I need to extract content from multiple files. With one file I used slurp and registered a variable.

```
- name: extract nameserver from .conf file
  slurp:
    src: /opt/test/roles/bind_testing/templates/zones/example_file.it.j2
  delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
  register: file

- debug:
   msg: "{{ file['content'] | b64decode }}"
```

But now I have multiple files so I need to extract content from every files, register them one by one to be able to process them later with operations like sed, merging_list etc...

How can I do this in ansible?

I tried to use slurp with with_fileglob directive but I couldn't register the files...

```
- name: extract nameserver from .conf file
  slurp:
    src: "{{ item }}"
  with_fileglob:
    - "/opt/test/roles/bind9_domain/templates/zones/*"
  delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
  register: file
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should just use the `loop` option, configured with the list of files to `slurp`. Check this example:

```
---
- hosts: local
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: Find out what the remote machine's mounts are
      slurp:
        src: '{{ item }}'
      register: files
      loop:
        - ./files/example.json
        - ./files/op_content.json

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item['content'] | b64decode }}"
      loop: '{{ files["results"] }}'
```

I am `slurping` each file, and then iterating through the `results` to get its content.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but i have 78 files in the dir, so:
 
`loop:
        - /my_dir/files1
        - /my_dir/files2
         ......
        - /my_dir/files78 `
I don't want to list them all

Comment: Then add a task on top to list the files and create the list programmatically. For example, take a look at the [`file`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/find_module.html) module to do that.

Comment: This just leads to an exception in Ansible... "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'content'"

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a host's mounts you could utilize ansible_facts.

```
    "ansible_mounts": example:

- name: Free-space.yml Date
  command: date

- name: Display more vars
  debug:
    msg:
    - "Variable list"
    - "diskfree_req is:  '{{diskfree_req}}' "
    - "mountname is:     '{{mountname}}' "

- name: PreTest for freespace
  vars: 
    deprecation_warnings: False
    #mountname: '/opt/oracle'
    mount: "{{ ansible_mounts | selectattr('mount','equalto', mountname) | first }}"

  assert:
    that: mount.size_available > {{diskfree_req}}
    msg: 
    - "DANGER : disk space is low"
    - "'{{mountname}} only has {{mount.size_available}} available. Please correct"
  register: disk_free
```